# Google API "Couldn't initialize" "Service 'mybusiness.googleapis.com' not found or permission denied."

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-my-business-api

I am on this page: https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/basic-setup

I have an access Key, but I am getting the following error when clicking "Enable the Google My Business API":

> "Couldn't initialize" "Service 'mybusiness.googleapis.com' not found or permission denied."

Does anyone know what is causing this please?

Thanks

Comment: did you go though  https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/oauth-setup?  Please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: There is no code. The Business API does not come up in the Google Cloud Platform, only Places, which is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the Prerequisites page:

```
https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/prereqs
```

I needed to create a new project for my organization and then I filled out the access request form and waited for approval.